# "Home" not changing in Breadcrumbs when switching languages (Locale)

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs, i18n-l10n

I am using Locale to translate content and menus.

Despite that, even when viewing a page in Spanish, the "Home" link in the breadcrumbs does not change to "Inicio".

What can I do to fix that?

I have attempted to create a node called "Home", translate it to be called "Inicio" and then changed the url to the homepage in the Configuration > Site Information but have still not had any success.

Is there a possibility to fix this without an additional module and a ton of re-configuring?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you customized breadcrumbs in template.php? If yes, then check if "Home" is written in t() function.

Comment: What version of Drupal? What contrib modules (if any) were used to construct breadcrumbs?

Comment: Thank you for the response. @VishalPatil - I have not customized Breadcrumbs at all in the template.php file (The only function I have is for custom page--**.tpl.php")

Comment: Thank you for the response. @oksana-c - I am using Drupal 7 (7.43). I have not used any other modules with it. Simply whatever was generated by default. I assume it is taking Breadcrumbs from the Main Menu. I am not sure if it means anything that my template is a sub-theme based on Zurb Foundation 5.

Comment: Go to "Translate strings" interface, search for "Home" and translate all untranslated instances of that string `/admin/config/regional/translate/translate`. See if that fixes you issue w/ breadcrumbs

Comment: @oksana-c, you are a life saver! Thank you very much! when I searched for "Home", fixing the first result happend to fix the issue I was having:

Home
/es/admin/config/regional/language/configure

Thank you again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped. I posted my comment as an answer, in case anybody else will be looking to solve same task. Also, added some tags to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **"Translate strings"** interface in **"Regional and language"** admin section (`/admin/config/regional/translate/translate`).

Search for "Home" and translate all untranslated instances of that string. This should fix the issue with translation of default breadcrumbs.

**Useful tip:** strings search is case sensitive, so make sure you enter your strings as they appear in html source (this condition gets easily overlooked).